# GetProcAddress strange behaviour on Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

On Python 2.7.10:

```
>>> from ctypes import windll
>>> windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA('kernel32'), 'LoadLibraryW')
```

Returns not null result. But the same on Python 3.X always returns null.

```
>>> from ctypes import windll
>>> windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA('kernel32'), 'LoadLibraryA')
0
# and other variants
>>> windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA('kernel32'), 'LoadLibraryW')
0
>>> windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32'), 'LoadLibraryA')
0
>>> windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32'), 'LoadLibraryW')
0
```

What's wrong and how to fix it (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` is a little unusual in terms of its handling of strings for the function name. Because exported function names are always encoded with 8 bit text, the procedure name argument has type `LPCSTR`.

The Python 2.7 string type, `str` is not Unicode, and when passed to `ctypes`, defaults to encoding the text as 8 bit. The Python 3.x string type is Unicode, and when passed to `ctypes`, defaults to encoding the text as 16 bit. Hence the failure.

Use `argtypes` and `restype` to be precise about types and resolve this.

```
>>> from ctypes import * # just for this answer, to save typing
>>> GetModuleHandle = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
>>> GetModuleHandle.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]
>>> GetModuleHandle.restype = c_void_p
>>> kernel32 = GetModuleHandle('kernel32')
>>> kernel32
2004418560
>>> 2004418560
2004418560
>>> GetProcAddress = windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress
>>> GetProcAddress.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]
>>> GetProcAddress.restype = c_void_p
>>> LoadLibraryW = GetProcAddress(kernel32, b'LoadLibraryW') # force 8 bit encoding
>>> LoadLibraryW
2004509856
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! It's works: windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32'), b'LoadLibraryW')